# Can't import plot_model from keras.utils

Tags: python, import, tf.keras

I'm trying to visualize a neural network model with plot_model,
but importing `plot_model` fails with an error message i don't understand.

My code:

```
# %% setup 
import os
import tensorflow as tf

tf_model_target_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tfModelDir')

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(tf_model_target_path)
# %% visualize model: save to image file 
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='model.jpg')
```

the line
`from keras.utils import plot_model`
throws:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'dispatch'
  File "{...}\kerasVisMinError.py", line 9, in <module>
    from keras.utils import plot_model
```

When i run the code from VSCode's IPython interactive shell, i get a more verbose error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
{...}\kerasVisMinError.py in <module>
      9 # %% visualize model: save to image file
----> 10 from keras.utils import plot_model
      11 #from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
      12 #plot_model(model, to_file='model.jpg')
      13 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     18 [keras.io](https://keras.io).
     19 """
---> 20 from keras import distribute
     21 from keras import models
     22 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\distribute\__init__.py in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18 from keras.distribute import sidecar_evaluator

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\distribute\sidecar_evaluator.py in <module>
     20 from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
     21 from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation
---> 22 from keras.optimizers.optimizer_experimental import (
...
---> 33 @tf.__internal__.dispatch.add_dispatch_support
     34 def epsilon():
     35     """Returns the value of the fuzz factor used in numeric expressions.

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'dispatch'
```

im using VS Code.

my python version is 3.8.3

my packages for keras, etc:

```
tensorflow             2.4.1
keras                  2.10.0
Keras-Preprocessing    1.1.2
keras-utils            1.0.13
```

I found a similar
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74353697/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-compat-v2-internal-has-no-attribute-dis) on SO that has no answer yet

I tried replacing the import line with `from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67720937/19251074), but i get the same error message

I created a [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12a1DHuIcTZhlc1sZZ9AJKhCc__ddo2-D?usp=sharing). There i'm able to import `plot_model` and then visualise my model

I tried to downgrade tensorflow to 2.3.1 as suggested
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67292804/19251074), but now i get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Miki\Documents\progi_peldak\pythonTensorflow\kerasVisMinErrorForSO\kerasVisMinError.py in <module>
      14 print(tf.version.VERSION)
      15 #from keras.utils import plot_model
----> 16 from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
      17 #plot_model(model, to_file='model.jpg')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     18 [keras.io](https://keras.io).
     19 """
---> 20 from keras import distribute
     21 from keras import models
     22 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\distribute\__init__.py in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18 from keras.distribute import sidecar_evaluator

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\distribute\sidecar_evaluator.py in <module>
     20 from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
     21 from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation
---> 22 from keras.optimizers.optimizer_experimental import (
     23     optimizer as optimizer_experimental,
...
---> 33 @tf.__internal__.dispatch.add_dispatch_support
     34 def epsilon():
     35     """Returns the value of the fuzz factor used in numeric expressions.

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are `Tensorflow` and `Keras` version mismatched in your system. You need to upgrade the tensorflow version to `TF 2.10` as you have installed `Keras` version `2.10`.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.10
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

Now import [plot_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model) api by providing a complete alias name:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
```